# How to get values from SQL query for every well id in Java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraywellslistsplit.length; i++) {
String wellid = arraywellslistsplit[i];
System.out.println(wellid);
String  sql = "select date_part('year', \"Date\") as year ,\"Oil\",concat(date_part('year',\"Date\"),'- 
',date_part('month',\"Date\")) as year_mon from table where \"Well ID\"= "+wellid+" group by  
year,\"Oil\",year_mon,\"Date\" order by \"Date\"";
System.out.println("\nExecuting query: " + sql);
return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, (rs, row) -> {
X xy= new X();
xy.setDate(rs.getString("year"));
xy.setOil(rs.getString("Oil"));
xy.setYear_mon(rs.getString("year_mon"));
System.out.println("listyear_mon ::  "+(rs.getString("year_mon")));
return xy;
});          
}
```

I want to return all well id values, not only one wellid value. I'm getting only one wellid columns even though I kept in for loop

Comment: Please tag only a **single** RDBMS... not 3...

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `where "Well ID" IN (...)`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: where "Well ID" IN (), I can use but will get as all columns as single JSON, But I want them as separately like for each wellid.

Answer (score 0):

You get only one well detail because loop is running only once, because when the code get to the `return` statement it break out from the loop. So don't use return statement inside the loop.

Comment: Yes exactly,but that is the problem i have now.I'm a learner in java.im not sure how to write statements.